# Linker errors with class template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, linker

I'm testing ADT linked list implementation.  It's from my college text from a previous semester and one of my current assignments requires me to use it. and it is derived from a more general linked List Type class.  I've been fighting this problem for hours, and cant figure out why it wont link.

this is main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "unorderedlinkedlist.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
unorderedLinkedList<int> newList;
for (int i = 1; i<=10;i++)
    newList.insertLast(pow(2,i));

newList.print();
return 0;
}
```

this is the header for the derived class:

```
#ifndef UNORDEREDLINKEDLIST_H
#define UNORDEREDLINKEDLIST_H
#include <iostream>
#include "linkedlisttype.h"


using namespace std;

template <class Type>
class unorderedLinkedList : public linkedListType<Type>
{
    public:
        /// Check to see if item already exists in the list
        bool search(const Type& searchItem) const;

        /// insert newItem at the beginning of the list
        void insertFirst(const Type& newItem);

        ///function to insert newItem at the end of the list
        void insertLast(const Type& newItem);

        /// delese deleteItem from the list
        void deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem);


    protected:

    private:
};


template <class Type>
bool unorderedLinkedList<Type>::search(const Type& searchItem) const
{
    nodeType<Type> *current;
    bool found = false;
    current = linkedListType<Type>::first;

    while (current != NULL && !found)
        if (current->info == searchItem)
            found = true;
        else current = current->link;

    return found;
}

template <class Type>
void unorderedLinkedList<Type>::insertFirst(const Type& newItem)
{
    nodeType<Type> *newNode;
    newNode = new nodeType<Type>;
    newNode->info = newItem;
    newNode->link = linkedListType<Type>::first;
   linkedListType<Type>::first = newNode;

    linkedListType<Type>::count++;

    if (linkedListType<Type>::last == NULL)
        linkedListType<Type>::last = newNode;
}

template <class Type>
void unorderedLinkedList<Type>::insertLast(const Type& newItem)
{
    nodeType<Type> *newNode;
    newNode = new nodeType<Type>;
    newNode->info = newItem;
    newNode->link = NULL;

    if (linkedListType<Type>::first == NULL)
    {
        linkedListType<Type>::first = newNode;
        linkedListType<Type>::last = newNode;
        linkedListType<Type>::count++;
    }
    else
    {
        linkedListType<Type>::last->link = newNode;
        linkedListType<Type>::last = newNode;
        linkedListType<Type>::count++;
    }
}

template <class Type>
void unorderedLinkedList<Type>::deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem)
{
   nodeType<Type> *current;
    nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent;
    bool found;

    if (linkedListType<Type>::first == NULL)
        cout << "You cannot delete soemthing from an empty list." << endl;

    else
    {
       if (linkedListType<Type>::first ->info == deleteItem)
        {
            current = linkedListType<Type>::first;
            linkedListType<Type>::first = linkedListType<Type>::first->link;
            linkedListType<Type>::count--;

            if (linkedListType<Type>::first == NULL)
                linkedListType<Type>::last = NULL;

            delete current;
        }
        else
        {
            found = false;
            trailCurrent = linkedListType<Type>::first;
            current = linkedListType<Type>::first->link;

            while (current != NULL && !found)
            {
                if(current->info != deleteItem)
                {
                    trailCurrent = current;
                    current = current->link;
                }
                else
                    found = true;
            }


            if(found)
            {
                trailCurrent->link = current->link;
                linkedListType<Type>::count--;

                if (linkedListType<Type>::last == current)
                linkedListType<Type>::last = trailCurrent;

                delete current;
            }
            else
                cout << "the item to be deleted is not in the list." << endl;
        }
    }
}
#endif // UNORDEREDLINKEDLIST_H
```

Linker errors:

> /tmp/cc9ozgPv.o:
>       (.rodata._ZTV14linkedListTypeIiE[_ZTV14linkedListTypeIiE]+0x20): undefined reference to `linkedListType<int>::search(int const&) const'
>    /tmp/cc9ozgPv.o:(.rodata._ZTV14linkedListTypeIiE[_ZTV14linkedListTypeIiE]+0x28): undefined reference to`linkedListType::insertFirst(int const&)'
>    /tmp/cc9ozgPv.o:(.rodata._ZTV14linkedListTypeIiE[_ZTV14linkedListTypeIiE]+0x30): undefined reference to `linkedListType<int>::insertLast(int const&)'
>    /tmp/cc9ozgPv.o:(.rodata._ZTV14linkedListTypeIiE[_ZTV14linkedListTypeIiE]+0x38): undefined reference to`linkedListType::deleteNode(int const&)'
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Shouldn't the methods of the derived template class be declared as inline?

Comment: I found what was going on.  perhaps there is an explanation for this that I've forgotten from previous semesters,  but the text had me declare the derived functions as virtual in the base header, though the definitions went into the  derived header... commenting those out got things working.